# Selecting a class with Jquery using a Javascript For loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so I have a class applied to a group of images. I am trying to create a for loop that will use the elements of a class for the for loop. I know in python you can go "for element in *thing*" and was wondering if there was something similar in Javascript. I found some information online about the javascript for/in loop and have the following code written:

```
    function walkingFeet(){
        for (foot in *class named walkingFoot*){
            [code to be executed]
        }
    }
```

I basically am just having trouble finding out what to put where the asterisks are and if that sort of syntax is something that I can even do with Javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With jQuery you'd only use `.each` anyway, but notice that the `for in`-loop is only designated for object property enumeration. On arrays (and array-like objects like NodeLists or jQuery collections) you should use standard `for` iteration (with a counter up to `.length`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged jquery ,You can loop through the `class` elements like

```
$('.yourClass').each(function() {
     alert(this.id);  
});
```

[Learn more here on each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this question with `jQuery`, so I assume you have access to it at this point of the script: It's easiest to be done with jQuery's `each`-function:

```
$('.element').each(function(index, element) {
    // index = the current index, the first would be 0
    // element = the html-dom-element, the same as 'this'

    // code to be executed
});
```

Comment: Definitely going to throw the each function in to my list of Jquery functions to commit to memory thanks!